# MLPClassfier predict and predict_proba seem inconsistent

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, classification

I am using the MLPClassifier using the lbfgs solver.

If I calculate the expected value using the predict_proba() method and the classes_ attribute, it does not match what the predict() method returns.

Which one is more accurate?

Does the value returned by predict() have to be one of the classes? Will it not interpolate between the classes? I have a continuously varying variable I want to predict.

Comment: Can you show the output from `predict_proba` and `predict` for cases where you found this inconsistency?

Comment: "Does the value returned by predict() have to be one of the classes? " - absolutely yes. That's the definition of classification. if you have " continuously varying variable",  you should use regression. But I guess I'm missing something here, what does your classes mean if I may ask?

Comment: By classes, I meant the *classes_* attribute of the MLPClassifier instance. It contained selected values of the input (Not sure how they were selected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Definition**

`predict` - classifies your input into a label.

`predict_proba` - returns the predicted probability for each class in your model.

**Example**

If this were a binary problem, and your classes labelled `0` and `1`. Then for some input you are testing, `predict` will return a class, let's say `1`.

However, `predict_proba` is going to give you the predicted probability that this input maps to class `1`, which could, in this example, be `0.8`. This is why their values do not match.

**Which is more accurate?**

You can't really compare their accuracy. However, you can treat the `predict_proba` as the confidence of your model for a particular class. For example, if you have three classes, and you tested one sample. Then you would receive an output of three real numbers:

`[0.11, 0.01, 0.88]`

You could treat this as your model having a high confidence that this input maps to the third class, as it has the highest probability of `0.88`.

In contrast, for some other input value, your model might spit out the following:

`[0.33, 0.32, 0.34]`

Your model still predicts the third class, as this has the highest probability. However, there is a low confidence that the third class is the *true* class.

Comment: Does the value returned by predict() have to be one of the classes? Will it not interpolate between the classes? I have a continuously varying variable I want to predict.

Comment: Yes. A classifier predicts a category. If you are trying to predict a continuous real value, you must use a regressor. See here

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html